# npm ws (websocket) close automatically after some time

Tags: node.js, web-services, sockets, npm, websocket

i am use [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package of npm in my node.js project for socket programming

here is my code....

```
var server = require('ws').Server;


var serverConnection = new server({port : 5000});

serverConnection.on('connection',function(ws){

    console.log('websocket is created on at ws://{{IP_ADDRESS}}:5000');

    ws.on('message',function(requestedString){

      var iCounter = 0;

      function doSetTimeout() {

         if(ws.readyState == 1)
         {
             iCounter = iCounter + 1;

             socketData = {'index' : iCounter}

             ws.send(JSON.stringify(socketData),function ack(error){

                  if(error){  
                      console.log("Occure error in socket");
                      console.log("error : "+error);
                  } 
             });
         }

         if(ws.readyState == 1)
         { 
              setTimeout(function() { 
                  doSetTimeout(i); 
              }, 15000);
         }

      }
  });

  ws.on('close', function close() {
      console.log('disconnected SOCKET - PORT : 5000');
  });
});
```

here in this example code of my programme you can see that it increment the value of `iCounter` and return me after every 15 seconds...

so when it get this output, sometime it close the connection automatically. i sow some issue of same like this for websocket. and peoples say that websocket have some timeout so in `npm ws` package socket, how can i increase the timeout. or is there any other issue for closing my websocket automatically???

first, sorry for my bad english..& please help me..

Comment: I'm getting this exact same problem (15 seconds and code 1006 to idle client). Did you ever figure out where the 15 second timeout is defined? I know that I can workaround it by sending dummy heartbeat signal every 10 seconds but I would rather increase the timeout to a minute or two to allow slower rate for the heartbeat messages, too. If I remember correctly, Google figured out years ago that even mobile phone clients can handle about 35 sec heartbeat signal without losing the connection so 10-15 seconds seems like too short timeout to me.

Comment: I've been reading source code for `ws`, `http` and `socket` libraries for hours but haven't been able to figure this one out. I have verified that this is not caused by the client because it happens even with e.g. `wscat`.

Answer (score 5):

First, what you need is: detecting reason why connection is closed. In onclose check `event.code`. Check codes in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent
(check this on server and client)

Probably you need use on server `ws.ping()` to maintaining the connection. (Some servers/proxies closse connection after 60s inactivity)

So, add in

```
serverConnection.on('connection',function(ws){
  let interval = setInterval(function(){ws.ping()}, 50e3)
  ws.on("close", function(ev) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log('disconnected SOCKET - PORT : 5000, reason: ' + ev.code);
  })
}
```

Close codes you can find here: https://github.com/Luka967/websocket-close-codes

Also in [`ev.reason`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent#properties) you can read more about it.

Comment: The client gets code `1006` without any text explanation and connection is dropped. I think it's caused by class `stream` running `emitCode()` but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen check `ev.reason` or codes list https://github.com/Luka967/websocket-close-codes